# How can I run two applications in one virtual directory in IIS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, web-applications, web

I have multiple web application in just one solution. I got problem in deploying and running both application in just one virtual directory in IIS.

Solution - 
    Project1
    Project2

Project1 can't access or call page from Project2.

I want the [**Project1**]Default.aspx to call webform from [**Project2**]Default.aspx using below code:

[Project1]Default.aspx.cs
Response.Redirect("../Project2/Default.aspx");

Please help me on this.

Comment: Well, what was your error?

Comment: It gives me a 404 error.

Comment: Still has error: 
Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found.

Comment: How did you deploy the site(s)/application(s)? Without this information, it'll be a guessing game.

Comment: P1 and P2 are different projects. They have their own bin folder,web config and some references. Do you think IIS only run the startup project [Project1]? so that i wasn't able to access other project [Project2] because it's not running in IIS?

Comment: I deployed it in just one virtual directory. I have Solution_Folder contains Project1_folder and Project2_folder. but in my virtual directory, you can only set one application so I set [Project1] and it's Default.aspx as the default document.

Comment: so files for project1 are there under Virtual Directory directly, saying that V=P1, now how you deployed P2 under Virtual Directory, so is it like V/P2?

Comment: Yes. That's how i deployed it.

Comment: okay. Then for P1 Default.aspx, it will be "~/Default.aspx" and for P2 Default.aspx, it will be "~/P2/Default.aspx".

Comment: I've already tried it but it's still giving me the 404 error. The resource cannot be found. Do i need to configure P2 in IIS? coz I just set P1 in the virtual directory.

Comment: sorry my bad.. it is virtual directory and not an application. then it should be like "~/V/Default.aspx" for P1 and "~/V/P2/Default.aspx" for P2.

Comment: I think there is problem in running P2. Do we really can deploy multiple application under single virtual directory? Even in my localhost, P1 and P2 can't communicate.

Comment: you will need to convert P2 into an application under IIS. Also, to see the actual error, if you are running IE, just uncheck "Show friendly HTTP error messages" under Internet Options > Advanced tab.

Comment: Yes you can have **nested applications**. Your best bet is to go over [IIS setup pertaining to virtual directories/applications](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis)